# collections of collection

Tags: java, jpa

`private Map<Integer,List<ProgramCourse>>` map where ProgramCourse is a domain class in my project and the above map is a field of my domain class Program when i am running the project 
following exception is coming.

> Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.sparshsoft.drps.domain.Program.programScheme[java.util.List]

Comment: What's the question? Why you're getting the error, or something actually related to collections of collections?

Comment: How it's related to Spring MVC, it's a Hibernate/JPA error.

Comment: i am trying to create tag spring mvc with hibernate jpa but does not succeded so i write spring mvc

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not support nested collections.  You will need to change it to a simpler data structure, initialize it in get/set methods, or create an object that defines the relationship.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices